# Jquery Ui Datepicker Colors and disable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am making a booking app now and have a problem. I need a calendar where the date range  for booking an apartment should be choosen.

So I have 3 main problems

1) Disable/Enable   I need to disable all  not bookable dates , which dinamically should be passed for each month .

I mean on month change I should make a json request to server which will give back for each given date  data like if it's possible to check in or no, and the color

2) Color problem... How to pass for each given date a class to color each day with specific color?

3) Always open...     Idaelly here what i want...

http://www.interhome.com/english/spain/costa+blanca/altea/es9740.272.1/price#Prices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find these useful:

[jQuery UI DatePicker: Disable Specified Days](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days)

[jQuery UI: Highlight multiple dates in jquery datepicker](http://www.emirplicanic.com/javascript/jquery-highlight-multiple-date.php)